# can't figure out why setTimeout() isn't functioning properly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So I'm trying to make it so I go to another website after a certain number of seconds, however it doesn't appear to be working. I would expect my code (below) to go to youtube for 10 seconds and then it would change into google. What is the problem? Much appreciated.

```
window.location.assign("http://www.youtube.com");
setTimeout(doSomething, 10000);
function doSomething()
{
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: Once you go to the other website, your page is dead and you have lost control of the user's navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.location.assign("http://www.youtube.com");
```

redirects to Youtube, so anything after that line is not executed as you're now on Youtube ?

Comment: So is there a way where you can redirect the page after a duration of time?

Comment: Additionally, If i get rid of the setTimeout statement in my code it will redirect me to http://www.google.com.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed, and you're already doing it, it just never reaches that redirect because you redirect before you get there

Comment: The reason you end up at Google is probably because the browser manages to parse both statement before redirecting, and decides you probably wanted the last one, that doesn't happen when you defer execution of the latter redirect.

Comment: Okay, then how would I fix my code so I can have it wait before it redirects?

Comment: Just remove the first redirect and keep the timeout? You can't redirect to one page, wait ten seconds, then redirect to another page, it's just not possible.

Comment: So then if I wanted to have a program that was doing something as I explained earlier should I write the program in a different language like Java or C++?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you do, once the user leaves the page and go to Youtube, you're no longer in control, you can't tell the browser to do anything, the user has left, regardless of what language you write in. The only exception would *maybe* be a browser extension, but that's something completely different.

Comment: Did I do that properly? @adeneo

Comment: @Andreas - Yes you did !

Answer (score 1):

Once the browser leaves the page your JavaScript stops processing too. You cant go to another site and then continue to run your JavaScript.